# Trouble understanding the use of void (*fptr)(void) pointer in an array of void

Tags: c

I have trouble understanding the code of a C program that is supposed to be vulnerable.

We have this definition `typedef void (*fptr)(void);`, and I leave the partial code above. I don't quite have a problem understanding the instruction `fptr p = pat_on_back;`, which just defines an fptr pointer that points to a function that never gets executed because that instruction just defines and initializes a pointer (right?).

My problem is understanding instruction `fptr  ptrs[3] = { NULL, get_wisdom, put_wisdom };`. How come this instruction works when the type fptr is clearly being used to declare and initialize an array of the void? Shouldn't just receive a single void parameter?

For the matter, the get_wisdom() and put_wisdom() functions both receive and return void. This little program is to fill and print a simple linked list of chars called 'wisdom'. The functions get_wisdom() and put_wisdom() does exactly what it apparently seems to do.

```
char greeting[] = "Hello there\n1. Receive wisdom\n2. Add wisdom\nSelection >";
char prompt[] = "Enter some wisdom\n";
char pat[] = "Achievement unlocked!\n";
char secret[] = "secret key";

typedef void (*fptr)(void);

void pat_on_back(void) {
  write(outfd, pat, sizeof(pat));
  return;
}

void put_wisdom(void) {
  . . .
}

void get_wisdom(void) {
  . . .
} 

fptr  ptrs[3] = { NULL, get_wisdom, put_wisdom };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  while(1) {
      char  buf[1024] = {0};
      int r;
      fptr p = pat_on_back;
      r = write(outfd, greeting, sizeof(greeting)-sizeof(char));
      if(r < 0) {
        break;
      }
      r = read(infd, buf, sizeof(buf)-sizeof(char));
      if(r > 0) {
        buf[r] = '\0';
        int s = atoi(buf);
        fptr tmp = ptrs[s];
        tmp();
      } else {
        break;
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fptr` is a type. `ptrs[3]` is an array of that type. Presumably, `get_wisdom` and `put_wisdom` are compatible with that type. And the type is not `void`. The type is  *"pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing"*.

Comment: What do you mean by an array of void? Your question isn't clear. Please clarify.

Comment: I think what he/she means is that get_wisdom is a function pointer, which point to a function that might have been defined as "void get_wisdom(void);". ptrs[3] is an array of function pointer of same type (definition).

Comment: @user3386109 but { NULL, get_wisdom, put_wisdom } is an array, not a function, isn't it? Sorry, if it sounds dumb.

Comment: There is no such thing as "an array of void"

Comment: @ThomVald Yes, and that array is being used to initialize the array called `ptrs[3]`. Each element of the array `ptr[3]`, and each element of the initializer `{NULL, get_wisdom, put_wisdom}` has type `fptr`. So the code is creating and initializing an array of function pointers.

Comment: The line `fptr tmp = ptrs[s];` takes one of the pointers from the array, and the next line `tmp();` calls that function.

Comment: @user3386109 So you're saying that a variable of type fptr could be either a pointer of a function of fptr type OR a point of array of functions fptr?.

Comment: No, `fptr` is a pointer to a function. Nothing else. The syntax `[3]` indicates that `ptrs` is an array.

Comment: @user3386109 I think I got this. So, let me get this straight: ptrs works here as a pointer to NULL which classifies as fptr type, and the other elements of the array too, so the syntax is correct and valid?

Comment: @ThomVald Most types work that way. Consider the difference between `char ch;` and `char ch_array[4];`. Both declarations used the type `char`, but `ch` is a single `char`, while `ch_array` is an array of `char`, specifically an array of length 4 of `char`. Function pointer types work the same way. `fptr x;` is a single function pointer, and `fptr funcs[3];` is an array of function pointers.

Comment: Look at your own code.  You declare `char buf[1024]`.  That is an array holding 1024 values of type `char`.  Now look at `fptr ptrs[3]`.  That is an array holding 3 values of type `fptr`.

Comment: @MikeHolt Oh, I see... So it works for a single function pointer or an array of function pointers. Got it. Thank you so much! C pointers have been always looked weird and hard for me.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you so much for your help! Not it's clear this instruction for me. Also the line tmp().

Comment: @ThomVald I think you're beginning to understand, but it's difficult to tell from your wording. The thing to take from this is that `fptr` doesn't change meanings between `fptr foo;` and `fptr arr[3];`. In both cases, it means exactly the same thing, namely: "a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing." The only thing that makes `arr` an array of function pointers instead of a single function pointer is the `[3]` at the end, **not** because the token `fptr` is somehow changing meanings.

Comment: @ThomVald Perhaps it would help if you thought of the `[3]` in the line `fptr  ptrs[3] = { NULL, get_wisdom, put_wisdom };` as answering the question "How many?", and the `fptr` as answering the question "Of what?". And in the absence of a `[N]` (such as in `fptr foo;`), the answer to the question "How many?" just defaults to "one".

Comment: @MikeHolt Yes, that's what I understood. Sorry, I admit my wording is confusing and bad written. As I remember, if you just call `arr`, it works as a pointer to the first element, `NULL`, which happens to fit the definition of "a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing", and so the other elements of the array.

Comment: @ThomVald Close, but not quite. An array identifier used in an expression without any index is automatically treated by the compiler as a pointer to the first element in the array. But in this case, each element is itself a pointer to a function. So `arr` used all by itself would be "a pointer to a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing".

Comment: In other words, `arr` would be of type `fptr *` (a pointer to an `fptr`). So if you had a function such as `void run_functions(fptr *array_of_function_pointers)`, you could call it and pass `arr` to it, as in `run_functions(arr);`. Which would be equivalent to `run_functions(&arr[0])`, where `&arr[0]` is *explicitly* saying "the address of element 0 of array `arr`".

Comment: @MikeHolt Yep. Thank you so much, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void (*fptr)(void);
```

Defines the fptr type as a pointer to a function that returns a
value of the indicated type (void) and requires the indicated parameters (void)

```
fptr  ptrs[3] = { NULL, get_wisdom, put_wisdom };
```

Defines ptrs as a vector of 3 elements, each is a pointer to one
function that has void as parameter (anything), and returns void.

- *ptrs[0] = NULL*;        The first pointer point to NULL.
- *ptrs[1] = get_wisdom*;  The second pointer point to the function "get_wisdom".
- *ptrs[2] = put_wisdom*;  The 
  third pointer point to the function "put_wisdom".